# iPhone SDK: is it possible to make standard movie player working in portrait orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried to use

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't change anything in a standard movie player. Screen rotates to landscape mode automatically and movie player does not respond to portrait rotation.

However, it works with usual view controllers. The SDK version is 3.1.2

I'm not going to use pre-set video orientation, I need only auto-rotation if it's possible.

Comment: What are trying to use? If you use MPMoviePlayer then this can be done fairly easily

Comment: Yes, sure, I use MPMoviePlayer but I haven't found any suitable methods in it's reference except setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait.

Comment: In 3.2 documentation I found an instance method shoudAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, separately for MPMoviePlayerViewController class. It's not available for the version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You must have created the custom class which extends to `UIViewController` and you have added the frame work called `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`, then in delegate method - `(void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification`  you need to add following line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```